# computing the relevant $P$-value. Also compute a 0.95 confidence interval for the unknown $u$.

Tags: statistics

Suppose measurements (in centimeters) are taken using an instrument. There is error in the measuring process and a measurement is assumed to be distributed $N(u, \sigma_0^2)$, where $u$ is the exact measurement and $\sigma_0^2 = 0.5$. If the $(n = 10)$ measurements $4.7, 5.5, 4.4, 3.3, 4.6, 5.3, 5.2, 4.8, 5.7, 5.3$ were obtained, assess the hypothesis $H_0 : u = 5$ by computing the relevant $P$-value. Also compute a $0.95$ confidence interval for the unknown $u$.

ans:

$95\%$ CI, $\bar{x} \pm 1.96\sqrt{\frac{0.5}{10}} = 4.88 \pm 0.4383 \to (4.442, 5.318)$

Where does $1.96$ come from?

$\bar{x}$ is the average of the measurements. $n = 10$ and $0.5$ is $\sigma_0^2$. Not sure where 1.96 comes from...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1.96

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that in general, a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ confidence interval (note $\alpha = 0.05$ for a $95\%$ confidence interval) for the mean of a normal distribution (when the standard deviation $\sigma_0$ is known) is given by 
$$\bar{x}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma_0}{\sqrt{n}},$$
where $\bar{x}$ is your sample mean, $n$ is the sample size, and $z_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the "$(1-\alpha/2)$ quantile" of the standard normal distribution, that is, it satisfies $P(Z\le z_{1-\alpha/2}) = 1 - \alpha/2$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$.

Now, since $\alpha = 0.05$ for a $95\%$ confidence interval, we need the value of $z_{1-0.05/2} = z_{0.975}$. It [turns out](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0.975+quantile+of+the+standard+normal+distribution+) that $z_{0.975}\approx 1.96$ (i.e. the value of $z$ such that $P(Z\le z) = 0.975$ where $Z\sim N(0,1)$ is (**approximately**) $z=1.96$), so this is where $1.96$ comes from.